# How to add image with specific size in navigation bar and status bar?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I'm adding image in navigation bar but image is expanding in all the navigation bar. [image].

I'm trying to achieve this this thing. How i can achieve this?

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it in SwiftUI, you can consider implementing two different "RoundedRectangle" with properties "cornerRadius" and "Offset" under "ZStack"

Comment: It's UIKit. Thanks

Comment: Refer to this https://medium.com/@matschmidy/swift-custom-navigation-bar-image-for-ios-11-large-titles-8a176d9cbaed